# Densenet from keras_contrib issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I am trying to use the [Densenet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/applications/densenet.py) from the keras_contrib for my own data with dimensions `(30k,2,96,96)`.

Is it not possible to use this implementation with my data of the shape? It gives following error and warning.

```
    Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 96, 96, 2)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
initial_conv2D (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 16)   288         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_0_0_bn (BatchNormalizatio (None, 96, 96, 16)   64          initial_conv2D[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 96, 96, 16)   0           dense_0_0_bn[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_0_0_conv2D (Conv2D)       (None, 96, 96, 4)    576         activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 96, 20)   0           initial_conv2D[0][0]             
                                                                 dense_0_0_conv2D[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
final_bn (BatchNormalization)   (None, 96, 96, 20)   80          concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 96, 96, 20)   0           final_bn[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 96, 96, 2)    42          activation_2[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,050
Trainable params: 978
Non-trainable params: 72
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Finished compiling
/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py:1213: UserWarning: Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) following the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (39840, 96, 96, 2) (2 channels).
  ' channels).')
/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py:1437: UserWarning: NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3, or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (39840, 96, 96, 2) (2 channels).
  str(self.x.shape[channels_axis]) + ' channels).')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_densenet.py", line 149, in <module>
    fit_model(X_train,y_train,X_val,y_val)
  File "keras_densenet.py", line 140, in fit_model
    verbose=2)
  File "/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1415, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 140, in fit_generator
    val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)
  File "/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 787, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/arka/anaconda2/envs/hyperas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 127, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (7440, 2)
```

This is how I am calling the Densenet function here. At least can tell me if this is possible to use two channel inputs with this Densenet function, will be a great help.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add a solution or ask a new question. Post your solution as an answer to your question. A new or further question should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: ok working on it. thanks.

Comment: [I posted the new question here as asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350285/densenet-from-keras-contrib-issue-part-ii)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says, it should have exactly 3 inputs channels. https://keras.io/applications/#densenet
You could use an embedding layer or maybe ad a dimension with constant values I guess.

Comment: I think this is only valid for transfer learning using the pretrained models on imagenet data i.e. For from scratch training I expect it to work though with two channel. My two channel contains two images i wanna compare.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by passing the `include_top=True` with `Classes=2` and pooling='avg'. Explanation: When `include_top` is set True a dense layer is added on top with as many classes with softmax as the activation function. Now dense layers expects one dimentional input. At this stage network was outputting 4 dimentional tensor which caused the error. When used pooling as 'avg', it applied a global average pooling, which collapsed the dimentions and made it flat, so dense can compute it. Personally I prefer `Flatten` at this stage though. Need to edit the densenet code for that.